# Sharing gridview selected item

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, share

I'm developing an UWP app. In my app there is gridview and I wants to develop it like when someone clicks on gridview item then share option appears. I have done some coding part but I getting null point exception. Anyone can help me with this code...

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="gridview" ItemClick="gridviewitemclick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding image}" Margin="2" Height="144" Width="256"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

C# class:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private GridView imageitem;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        loaddata();

        DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareImageHandler);

    }

    private void loaddata()
    {
        List<Class1> listimage = new List<Class1>
        {
            new Class1 {image="ms-appx:///images/Blo.png" },
            new Class1 {image="ms-appx:///images/Bun.png" },
            new Class1 {image="ms-appx:///images/Cght.png" },
            new Class1 {image="ms-appx:///images/rld.png" },
            new Class1 {image="ms-appx:///images/Usa.png" },
            new Class1 {image="ms-appx:///images/Wing.png" },
        };
        gridview.ItemsSource = listimage;
    }


    private async void ShareImageHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRequest request = e.Request;
        DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();

        try
        {

            StorageFile imagefiles = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageitem.SelectedItem.ToString());
            request.Data.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(imagefiles));
        }
        catch
        {
            request.FailWithDisplayText("Select an image you would like to share and try again.");
        }
        finally
        {
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }

    private void gridviewitemclick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enable item click in a Grid View, it does not cause the item to be selected. That means that the `imageitem.SelectedItem` property is `null` inside the `ShareImageHandler`.

A simple solution for this would be to update the `gridviewitemclick` method to cache the clicked item:

```
private Class1 _lastClickedItem = null;

private void gridviewitemclick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    _lastClickedItem = e.ClickedItem as Class1;
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

And now inside the `ShareImageHandler` use this variable to access the item user clicked (replacing the `imageitem.SelectedItem` reference). You also need to change the way you retrieve the file a little, using the `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync`, because the file paths in your class are absolute URIs.

```
StorageFile imagefiles = 
   await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync( new Uri(  _lastClickedItem.image ) );
```

Comment: After doing changes I m getting exception 'IO.FileNotFound'

Comment: The problem was in the `GetFileAsync` call. You were calling `ToString()` but that just returns the type name of `Class1`. I have updated my answer with the solution.